# how to determine if the Tpicture are contain Jpeg?

Tags: delphi, image

i am using delphi7/2009. how to determine the content of Tpicture? jpeg bmp png etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (APicture.Graphic is TBitmap) then
result := true 
else 
result := false;
```

// replace TBitmap make it other format //

Answer (score 6):

```
   if Picture.Graphic is TJPegImage then
     ShowMessage('JPEG')
   else if Picture.Graphic is TBitmap then
     ShowMessage('Bitmap');
//etc
```